# locationManager:didEnterRegion method is not getting called when screen is off

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

I have been doing an app to detect beacons. The app works great when the app is in foreground or screen is on. But locationManager:didEnterRegion method is not getting called when screen is off. As I know, locationManager:didEnterRegion should be called either way.

I have tried many scenarios like wait 15+ minutes after enter a region, different configurations (notifyEntryStateOnDisplay=true or false)... but the result is the same. locationManager:didEnterRegion method is not getting called until unlock the phone.

PS: locationManager:didExitRegion is getting called properly when screen is off.

I used iPhone 5, 5S and 6 plus to test the app on IOS 8.1

Edit: "Location updates" and "Uses Bluetooth LE accessories" are enabled

Thank you for your answers.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
var lastProximity: CLProximity?

let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(
    proximityUUID: NSUUID(UUIDString:"d2c36ec5-dfsb-46d2-b069-d2f3r51996e0"),
    identifier: "My region"
)    

func application(application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
        self.beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = true
        self.beaconRegion.notifyOnExit = true
        self.beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = false

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()

        if(locationManager!.respondsToSelector("requestAlwaysAuthorization")) {
            locationManager!.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }

        locationManager!.delegate = self
        locationManager!.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false

        locationManager!.startMonitoringForRegion(beaconRegion)
        locationManager!.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion)
        locationManager!.startUpdatingLocation()

        return true
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    didDetermineState state: CLRegionState,
    forRegion region: CLRegion!) {
        NSLog("State determined")
}              

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    didRangeBeacons beacons: [AnyObject]!,
    inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion!) {
        NSLog("didRangeBeacons")
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    didEnterRegion region: CLRegion!) {
    NSLog("didEnterRegion")

    manager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region as CLBeaconRegion)
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    didExitRegion region: CLRegion!) {
    NSLog("didExitRegion")            
    manager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region as CLBeaconRegion)
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    monitoringDidFailForRegion region: CLRegion!,
    withError error: NSError!) {
    NSLog("monitoringDidFailForRegion - error: %@", [error.localizedDescription]);
}    



}
```

Comment: Try removing the passcode lock screen on your device, and repeat the test. Depending on what you are trying to do when user enters the region, the lock screen may interfere. Obviously turning off the lock screen is not a solution but may give clues as to the real problem.

Comment: The passcode is already disabled while I test the app

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable background execution mode for the app.

Put the required key and value in your `info.plist`:

[image]

Comment: "Location updates" and "Uses Bluetooth LE accessories" are enabled

Comment: I don't think this is correct. It certainly isn't needed for non-beacon region monitoring and will get your app rejected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" key in your info.plist file that gives the message to display to the user to go along with the `requestAlwaysAuthorization` call.

Here is an example:

[image]

If you ran your app before you had these plist entries set up, you might need to uninstall and reinstall for it to work properly.

Comment: Thank you but I have already added NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription to info.plist before install the applicaton.

Answer (score 0):

which hardware do you use to send iBeacon signal?
I have had nearly the same problem as yours and I find the solution by accident. I firstly use rad Beacon USB act as iBeacon but it cannot wake up a screen off iPhone. But when I use an APP named Broadcaster run on another iOS device to send iBeacon signal, it success.

Maybe useful:
[iOS Can not find the iBeacon again in fore ground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27961587/ios-can-not-find-the-ibeacon-again-in-fore-ground/28492030#28492030)